# Owin Web Api in existing project, stop capturing all requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, mixing

For this current project I am working on, we need to implement a web api. It needs to live inside the existing webforms project. And the specifications say we need to use Owin.

So after wiring everything up using: Microsoft.Owin, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Microsoft.Owin.Hosting, Microsoft.Owin.Security

A proper startup class with the OwinStartupAttribute.
app.UseWebApi with a windsor IOC container.
Web api seems to work as expected.

Except for the fact that all requests made to the existing website also go through to webapi.

A bit more explanation.
We needed a LanguageMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler. After setting that class up we've started noticing that the breakpoint on 'SendAsync gets caught even when we are not requesting anything webApi related.

The older website shouldn't even have knowledge about this handler.

A bit code the clarify:

The startupclass:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(Startup))]
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var container = ((IContainerAccessor)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance).Container;


        app.UseWebApi(container);


    }
}
```

The UseWebApi extension:

```
    public static void UseWebApi(this IAppBuilder app, IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration
        {
            DependencyResolver = new WindsorDependencyResolver(container)
        };

        //Web API Routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


        //Default to json when requested by browser
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new RequestHeaderMapping("Accept", "text/html", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, true, "application/json"));

        //Add language handler
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new LanguageMessageHandler());


        //Ensure initialized
        config.EnsureInitialized();

        //Start WebApi
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

So now we are trying to figure out why all the requests are handled by the LanguageMessageHandler and not just the requests that are made for webApi.

An example route:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/dossier")]
public class AdministrationsController : ApiController
{
    //GET
    [Route("{idtype}_{id}/administrations/planned/")] //?limit={maxdate}&nursingunit={nuid}
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Planned(string idtype, int id, [FromUri] int maxdate = 6, [FromUri] int? nuid = null)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using a filter instead of a message handler.
Was wrongfully asuming that message handler was going to be executed after routing in the pipeline.